# Freestyle step platforms vs treadmills

Tags: cardio, bicycling, treadmill, machine

How does just stepping up and down (a basic step) on a step platform compare with a treadmill? Can I just do basic steps while watching TV for my cardio workouts?

How do they compare with stationary bikes?

Main goals are general fitness (cardio and muscular endurance)

Comment: Compare in what regard? For fitness? Calories burned? Muscle tone? Ability to walk up stairs or ride a bike?

Comment: @DarkHippo General fitness (cardio and muscle endurance).